# Words don't wrap inside redefined \marginpar{}

Tags: line-breaking, marginpar

I have tried to play with a MWE from @cmhughes in [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68482/marginpar-border-with-grey-background-and-round-black-edges/68558#68558), and discovered that words inside `\marginpar` do not wrap like they should. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,oneside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}                       
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[2][rectangle,draw,fill=black, text=white ,rounded corners]{
    \oldmarginpar{
    \scriptsize \tikz \node at (0,0) [#1]{#2};}
    }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\marginpar{margin text here, but it doesnt wrap like it should!!!}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I also discovered that if I put for example `$$m = 0$$` inside `\marginpar{}` it wont go into a new line like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `text width` in the option for node. (I used `text width= 2cm,` here which you can change for your requirement.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,oneside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[2][rectangle,draw,fill=black, text=white,text width= 2cm,rounded corners]{
    \oldmarginpar{
    \scriptsize \tikz \node at (0,0) [#1]{#2};}
    }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\marginpar{margin text here, but it doesnt wrap like it should!!!}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]